# PDF Form merging with itext. c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have to merge 2 pdfs forms into one. The input pdfs have fillable fields, and the output should also have the same fields. I was able to achieve this, but, when I merge PDFs with same value for fields, only the first field is coming aas a field and second one is flattened. (Lets say pdf 1 has fields 'Name' and 'Comment1'; pdf 2 has fields, 'Name' and 'Comment2'; when I merge, in the output pdf, 2nd 'Name' field is flattend.)

```
     _stamp = new PdfStamper(_reader, pdfStream);

         AcroFields fields = _stamp.AcroFields;

            if (!(fields == null))
                    {
                    _stamp.FormFlattening = false;

                    }

                    _stamp.Close();
                    _stamp = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are using `PdfStamper`. That's a class to fill out forms, not to merge them. Merging forms is done using `PdfCopy`:

```
public void createPdf(String filename, PdfReader[] readers) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    copy.setMergeFields();
    document.open();
    for (PdfReader reader : readers) {
        copy.addDocument(reader);
    }
    document.close();
    for (PdfReader reader : readers) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

You can find the full code samples [here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms). You'll have to adapt it to C# (the method names are slightly different, but the code is similar).

It is very important that you don't forget to tell `PdfCopy` that you want to merge the fields, otherwise the form will not be copied.

You explain that you have a field named `Name` in one PDF and a field named `Name` in the other. If you merge both forms, this will result in a single field `Name` with only one value. You can't have a field `Name` on one page with one value and a field `Name` on another page with another value. That's why we also provide a sample where the fields are renamed. You can find that example [here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms2). You probably don't need that example; I'm only adding it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, your examples helped a lot !!